# Windows Forms in Visual Studio Express

Tags: windows, forms

Good day, can I ask one question about Windows Forms? As far as I know Windows Forms is Win32 wrapper like MFC, created for use with .NET. But, what I dont know is, can you use windows forms and compile directly to native code? Becouse in Visual Studio Express, there is windows forms available only for CLR. And, there is no GUI tool for use with win32 project. I expected there will be one, since its called Visual, like Visual Basic has. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can great windows forms the same way as web forms in visual studio. Drag and drop controls ect. Just download the [IDE](http://windowsclient.net/edownloads.aspx)
See the rest of the http://windowsclient.net/ site for more information and how to start

Answer (score 0):

for a win32 project you wont get a GUI resource editor in Visual C++.
but for an MFC project you will get the dialog editor.

But compared to Windows Forms editor, the gui editor for MFC is just a basic one. i.e you wont get total control over the UI design. thing like (setting color to control, changing fonts etc).